# Firefox: how show thumbnails without open a new tab?

Tags: firefox

when I open new tab, the most or last visited websites are shown as small thumbnails, so I click one of them, visit it, but...how to show again the thumbnails of last visited websites? should I open a new tab again really???

Comment: Where exactly do you want to show them?

Comment: you question is not clear dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox Preferences, Change General tab=> Home page to `about:newtab`. That will do..
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just want to add that I have to click on on the homepage icon next to Downloads icon to get those thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

The [new tab page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites) is accessible using the special URL `about:newtab`.